# "The FFA was created to govern the rules of flying."

Tags: vocabulary, learning, reading, ielts

**Do those sentences have the same meaning?**

> - The FFA was created to govern the rules of flying.
> - The FFA was established to give rules to flying.

Comment: You should riformulate the question, in the very first line.

Comment: yeah I changed it

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELL. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), for example, by showing what your own personal research has shown, and why that does not answer the question.

Comment: You changed a correct sentence to a wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Give rules* implies that it *made* the rules.

*Govern the rules* implies that the rules already existed and the organisation was set up to make sure that people kept them.

Answer (score 1):

**Create** and **establish** may almost be considered consecutive processes.

**Create** means to bring into existence using material and/or conceptual inputs that had no obvious relationship to the creation before the creation came into existence. The more obvious such relationship may be, the less “creative” is the creation.

**Establish** almost contains the word “stable”, and is closely related. It means to make firm and enduring.

Examples:

**Information**

**Creating a fact** is a contradiction in terms, because it would imply that the fact does not follow from previously available information and logic. (One can, however, create an alternative fact.)

When information is created it starts with the creation of a hypothesis, which is a supposed explanation. Then a theory is created, which describes by analysis what observations and/or experiments would tend to support or refute the hypothesis, while tending to have the opposite effect on any competing hypotheses.

If the experiments and/or observations thus posited support the hypothesis, then it is established as a fact, i.e. considered unlikely to be refuted, or to cause disappointment when used as a basis for decisions.

Although the above terms are often used to describe science, the above process is equally applicable to establishment of any sort of facts. For example, lawyers construct their cases around “theories”, using that word in the same way. Then a judge or jury makes the ultimate decision as to whether their case is established.

Even a simple fact, such as “My car keys are under the sofa cushion.” follows from the above process of creation (“Maybe they fell out of my pocket on the sofa.”) through theory (“I can check by feeling under the cushion.”) to establishment (“Here they are!”).

**A Work of Art**

A work of art is created when the work has no obvious relationship to the components that went into it. The components may include themes (musical or otherwise) from previous works, but the work will not be considered “creative”, but instead “derivative”, if the new work could have easily been derived from previously existing work.

A work of art becomes established when it is known and liked by most connoisseurs of the art form, and is expected to remain so for a long time.

**A Firm**

One may create a business, if one starts it with little previous activity in that field in that area. This might include designing and building plant from the ground up, and hiring and training employees with no previous, relevant training or experience because no such candidates exist.

A business becomes established as a “firm” when it has lasted long enough, and become large and prosperous enough, that it seems likely to endure indefinitely. Some long-standing businesses advertise that they were established at some time decades or even centuries ago, although nowadays they tend more to emphasize modernity. In no case does a business advertise that it was established recently, because that would be a contradiction in terms.